# Checkbox check mark is always present while the attribute is not

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an issue with my code so when I click in my checkbox, my checkbox state has been put at false but I have always the mark/tick present whereas it doesn't normally be here...
My code:

```
<template>
  <div id="demo">
    <form action="#/login" >
      <input type="email" placeholder="Insérez votre adresse-mail pour créer votre compte"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Mettez y votre mot de passe">
      <label for="admin"> Droits administrateurs </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="admin" v-model="checked" @change="noEntry">
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  name: "Signup",
    data () {
      return {
        checked: false,
      }
    },
    methods : {
      noEntry()
      {      let password;
        password = !this.checked ?
            "" :
            prompt("Seul le personnel de la librairie y a accès, veuillez inscrire le mot de passe", "");
        password === "administrations" ? this.checked = true : this.checked = false
        console.log(this.checked)
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Picture of the problem :

[image: Checkbox_mark]

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with your code but it is working fine as per your expectations.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      checked: false,
      password: null
    }
  },
  methods : {
    noEntry() {
     let password;
     password = !this.checked ?
       "" :
     prompt("Seul le personnel de la librairie y a accès, veuillez inscrire le mot de passe", "");
     this.checked = (password === 'administrations')  ?  true : false
     console.log(this.checked);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" id="admin" v-model="checked" @change="noEntry">
</div>
```

My suggestion **:** Use `v-model` directive in the password field to get the value instead of using prompt.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      checked: false,
      password: null
    }
  },
  methods : {
    noEntry() {
     this.checked = (this.password === 'administrations')  ?  true : false
     console.log(this.checked);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Mettez y votre mot de passe">
  <input type="checkbox" id="admin" v-model="checked" @change="noEntry">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, it worked in your snippet but in my vue, my state is false but the tick is always here... I can't understand it...

Comment: Your code looks fine only and it should work. You can try to debug it step by step and try to find the root cause.

Comment: I add this at the end of the code :       document.getElementById("admin").checked = false ... otherwise doesn't work